# How to compute a weighted mean as a measure of central tendency?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, data, distributions, filtering, dataset

Imagine I have data points in triplicates, as follows
$$
L=\begin{pmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13}\\
p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23}\\
& \vdots &\\
p_{n1} & p_{n2} & p_{n3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
What is the best way to filter this data, so that I remove outliers and end up with a vector of best-fit values
$$
\tilde{L}=(\tilde{p}_1,\tilde{p}_2,\cdots,\tilde{p}_n)
$$
**Thoughts:** For example, if I have the plot

```
list = Table[
   If[j == 5, {0.6, 0.7, 0.1}, 
    RandomReal[{0. + 0.1 j, 0.3 + 0.1 j}, 3]], {j, 6}];
ListPlot[Transpose@list, PlotStyle -> Black, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I could naturally take the mean of these values (in blue)

```
Show[
 ListPlot[Transpose@list, PlotStyle -> Black, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All],
 ListPlot[Transpose@{Range[6], Mean /@ list}, PlotStyle -> Blue]
 ]
```

[image]

but clearly, at $n=5$ I have a potential outlier, which could be removed for a better fit. What would be the ideal technique to **assign a weighted mean to each triplicate based on the overall dataset**, possibly based on the average standard deviation between triplicates? I have heard about [Cook's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%27s_distance), but I am not too sure how to apply it here.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a good question but it would seem to be a better question for https://stats.stackexchange.com.  And there you'll certainly be asked about why you're tossing out data.  For example, is there some reason for tossing a point (such as the thermocouple broke) rather than the point just doesn't look like it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate outlier, you may e.g. fit a linear function to your data and subtract it from the data to get the deviations. Then calculate the standard deviation: std of the deviations. Now you can reject data points that differ more than some multiple (here e.g. 2) of the std from the fit. Here is an example:

```
dat = Flatten[
   Table[{j, 
     If[j == 5, {0.6, 0.7, 0.1}[[i]], 
      RandomReal[{0. + 0.1  j, 0.3 + 0.1  j}]]}, {j, 6}, {i, 3}], 1];
lin[x_] = Fit[dat, {1, x}, x];
std = StandardDeviation[t = dat[[All, 2]] - lin /@ dat[[All, 1]]];
dat1 = DeleteCases[dat, {x_, y_} /; Abs[y - lin[x]] > 2  std];
ListPlot[dat1, ImageSize -> {300, 200}]
```

[image]